# React how to apply`componentDidMount()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I am using redux and reactjs. I need to add few function in  `componentDidMount()` to the following root react component.

I am not using react class extend. How can I apply `componentDidMount()` and my logic there?

```
   const App = () => (
      <div>
        <NavigationContainer />
      </div>
    )

export default App
```

Comment: its a `stateless functional component`, lifecycle method will not be available here, what logic you want to put inside `componentDidMount` ?

Comment: I need to dispatch an action when redux app init. Do you have another idea how to achieve the same result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap the JSX in a return call and simply do your logic before, even interacting with your redux store.

```
const App = () => {
  const willRunOnEachRender = 'runs on each render'
  return (<div>
    <NavigationContainer willRunOnEachRender={willRunOnEachRender} />
  </div>
 )
}
export default App
```

Answer (score 0):

```
        import Dispatcher from "./Dispatcher.jsx";
   class TodoStore extends EventEmitter
{
      getInitialState: function() {
        return { };
      },

      componentWillMount: function() {

      },
changeevent()
{
.. your logic
this.emit("change");
}

      componentDidMount: function() {


    ..your logic 
      },
      handleActions(action)
                {
    if(action='your action')
{
changevent()
}
                }
      )

      window.Dispatcher=Dispatcher;
            Dispatcher.register(todoStore.handleActions.bind(todoStore));

 after the change event is fired in changevent you can catch that event wherever you want
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case you need to use stateful components or wrap it inside a stateful container, stateless components don't support the lifecycle in React.

So I recommend you import component from react and do something like below code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    //your code here
  }
  render() {
    return <div><NavigationContainer /></div>;
  }
}

export default App
```